# binding data from controller into select box in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application with Angular js.

I am retrieving a JSON and display in a HTML form.

HTML:

```
<select class="select optional" ng-model="to"
        ng-init="to=$parent.$eval('eligibiltyRules.condition.itineraryZone.to')">
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="Euro">Euro</option>
    <option value="Rupees">Rupees</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
myApp.controller('eligibilityController', function($scope,sharedProperties) {
    $scope.eligibiltyRules=[];
    $scope.eligibiltyRules = sharedProperties.getProductEligibilityData();
    console.log($scope.eligibiltyRules); //contains the JSON to be displayed in the form
    console.log($scope.eligibiltyRules.condition.itineraryZone.to); //contains data to be displayed in selectbox
});
```

I am able to display the respective JSON values in other form elements.
But not able to populate the data to be displayed in select box.

Please Advice

Comment: You want [ng-options](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select).  The syntax is a little complicated, but it will do what you want.

Comment: I did it.But it displays each letter in my JSON value as its options

Comment: You need to investigate the exact syntax.  You probably want something like ng-options="data.value for data in dataList"

Comment: Just a side note: never assign ng-model to a property directly on scope. There should always be a '.' in there, like ng-model="data.selected". See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m